# Meteor fall after update to 1.0.3.2 version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor

> /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
>                                                   throw(ex);
>                                                         ^ TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
>       at Object.exports.parse (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/parse-stack.js:18:26)
>       at Object.exception (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:478:28)
>       at /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:742:20
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at compileUnibuild (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:325:5)
>       at /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:135:26
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at Object.compiler.compile (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:131:5)
>       at /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2023:24
>       at /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:264:13
>       at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
>       at /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:257:29
>       at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
>       at /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:255:18
>       at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
>       at /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:246:23
>       at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
>       at Object.capture (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:245:19)
>       at Object.exports.bundle (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1975:31)
>       at bundleApp (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:508:34)
>       at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:544:35)
>       at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:771:28)
>       at /home/puzo/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:366:12

I try to run it but my app falls. I'm using the new version of `urigo:angular` and `angular-ui-router` packages. After add their to my project my app fall when I try to run it. The newest version isn't working for me I can use just 0.6 version of `urigo:angular` package.

Comment: From which Meteor version did you upgrade?

Comment: from 1.0.3.1 version, it happened after adding additional package